# Can I have a ~destructor(void)?

Tags: c++, standards

Looking at some old code of mine, I see that out of clumsiness I defined a destructor like so :

```
~ResourceManager(void);
```

This not only compiles, but works as expected. I changed it of course to

```
~ResourceManager();
```

but was I too quick to refactor? Is the first version correct and good C++ style?

### EDIT

Since the question was closed and won't get any chance for proper disambiguation, I should put the related quote from the standard **that answers this question, when destructors are put in perspective**

**12.4** Destructors

> 1. A special declarator syntax using an optional function-specifier (7.1.2) followed by ˜ followed by the destructor’s class name followed by **an empty parameter list** is used to declare the destructor in a class definition. In such a declaration, the ˜ followed by the destructor’s class name can be enclosed in optional parentheses; such parentheses are ignored. A typedef-name shall not be used as the class-name following the ∼ in the declarator for a destructor declaration.

So **the standard mandates an empty parameter list**. Maybe backwards compatibility with C  practices for **free functions** (where `f(void)` is the way to declare an empty parameter list) took destructors along with them in implementations, but it **certainly doesn't seem to be valid C++**.

Comment: The `void` parameter makes no difference. It is a C-ism, where it actually makes a difference. You don't need it in C++.

Comment: Style-wise, leave `void` out. You'll almost never see it written that way.

Comment: Woops. I should have checked if it was a dupe. :(

Comment: @juanchopanza The question linked as duplicate does not put destructors in perpsective (nor any other member functions).

Comment: What "perspective" is needed? The duplicate explains the meaning of void as function parameter.

Answer (score 7):

This is a remnant from C. In C the empty parameter list does not mean a function that takes no arguments, but rather a function with unspecified number of arguments. In C++ `foo(void)` is deprecated, and `foo()` is preferred, as it specifically means a function that takes no parameters. The same goes with your destructor as well. Although, the two lines of code are equivalent you should prefer the `~ResourceManager()` version.

Comment: Hence in C: void f(); f(1, 2, 3) is ok, but void g(void); g(1, 2, 3), not ???

Comment: @DieterLücking correct.

Answer (score 2):

There's no difference between these two lines of code. `()` is the same as `(void)`. From a style perspective, `()` is what I've always seen for functions with no argument.

Answer (score 2):

Both lines are equivalent. Some developers like to explicit `(void)` in signature of parameterless functions to say to anyone reading it "It does not take any parameters"